# IABv3 SKU is available, but cannot be purchased

Tags: in-app-billing, google-play-console

I have implemented in-app-billing for Android many times. But for my latest app, I can not get the purchase working.

I use IABv3.

When I do the `queryInventoryAsync()` I got proper results: my SKU is found, and I even see its price, description, etc, in the log.

**So the in-app product exists, and can be queried.**

Yet, when I purchase it, I see:
*The item you requested is not available for purchase.*

And IabHelper reports:

`Purchase canceled - Response: 4:Item unavailable`

- working code in other apps.
- app state is PUBLISHED.
- there is an ALPHA and a BETA track, both with uploaded APKs.
- google account is listed as test user.
- item is active.

What could be causing a situation where the queryInventory **does** see the product, but the purchase request **does not** see the product?

UPDATE: It started working without any changes. Somehow there was a large delay. I wonder if it has to do with the review, or the age-rating review?

Comment: Is item for purchase enabled in Google Play console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working (without me doing any changes) roughly at the time I received an email with this:

[image]

If I had to guess, the IAB item was blocked until the app was rated or reviewed otherwise by Google.